# Can't create database in SQL SSAS

Tags: ssas

I installed Microsoft SQL Analysis Service because I need it to run a forecast analysis from Excel using the Data Mining Plug-in.

When I open MS Management Studio and connect to the SSAS I don't know how to create a new database.

When I right-click over `Databases` there is nothing like `Create Database` or `New Database`.

This is the image of my problem:

[image: http://ibin.co/22fEN7JMkeF8]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well... I solved my problem reinstalling the suite selecting all of its options.

I still don't know what may cause this problem if not chosen in the instalation options but now I have the `New Database` option and could finish my job.

Thanks.

Comment: If reinstallation alone does not help, you may have to select the **Multidimensional and Data Mining** mode when installing SSAS (instead of the default **Tabular** mode): https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/282941/221692

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this problem by switching Analysis Services from Tabular to Multidimensional mode:

- Stop SQL Server Analysis Services service
- Go to the config folder, e.g. *C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSAS15.SQL2019\OLAP\Config*
- Copy file *msmdsrv.ini* to another folder (you can't edit it here directly)
- Open the copied file and search for the *DeploymentMode* xml tag
- Set the value to zero
- Save the file, copy it back to the Config folder
- Start the service

Answer (score -1):

You can use SQL Server Management Studio to create a new, empty database on an instance of SQL Server Analysis Services.
To create an Analysis Services database
Connect to an Analysis Services instance.
In Object Explorer, expand the node for the connected Analysis Services instance.
Right-click the Databases node of the Analysis Services instance and select New Database.
In the New Database dialog box, in Database name, type the name of the new database.
In Impersonation, provide impersonation information for the new database.
In Description, type the optional description for the new database.
Click OK.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but that is my problem. As I said there is no `New Database` option for me.

Comment: aight click this lik my be you will find same helpfulhttps://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189710(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: I doesn't help me because I can't see the `New Database` option. Maybe this picture makes things more clear: http://ibin.co/22fEN7JMkeF8